# Why is there a long time before csc kicks off in my ASP.NET Core project with large dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

My verbose compiler output for my asp.net core project looks like this:

**15:35:04**:191    1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;................ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /nullable:disable ..........(followed by a whole bunch of project references and files to compile)

**15:35:13**:317    1>    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.0-3.23517.17 (9d4cc030)

15:35:13:317    1>    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

You see how there is a 9 seconds gap between the 2 lines? This happens every time, even when there is a small white space change in something like Program.cs. Is this because I have a large number of dependent projects? If so, why isn't MSBuild using any kind of caching to speed this up for incremental builds? Or is there any other way to speed things up?

Comment: MSBuild will visit each project in the `ProjectReference` item collection. If the project is not already up-to-date, MSBuild will build it. It would be worth analyzing the logs to see if certain dependent projects are taking an inordinate amount of time. There may be a project that is not completely incremental and performs work regardless of being up-to-date.

Comment: Yea, this is a verbose log and nothing else is being logged during that 9 sec gap - all quiet strangely! There are 5 direct dependent projects but they in turn have a lot of other dependencies (but I would think all that shouldn't matter or does it?) since the incremental white space change happened only in the Program.cs.

Comment: It does matter. Each project in the 'tree' of project references will be visited. A consuming project doesn't cache that a dependent project was up to date on the last build because projects can be built independently. (Although I believe that once a project has been checked and found to be up to date it will not be rechecked in the same build session, i.e. if it is a dependency of multiple consuming projects it will be checked once.)